# I installed scott user creating file but It wasn't the scott It mentioned like USER is ""

Tags: oracle

[image]

as u know it usually downloads together with scott.sql file but Idk why but It couldn't download it so, eventually, I did it by myself. even directory wasn't created so I made it those by myself as well. anyway, even though I did it and succeeded to create user, it didn't have the name like that pic and as u know we don't have any way to change user's name so I couldn't. How can I change it to scott like normal?

Comment: You may want to try rewording your question.  It isn't clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: I installed scott but when I command like 'show user' it showed me like 'user is " "' so I wonder what's the prob anyway I found the solution and I succeeded to create scott user :) anyway ty to reply me

Comment: Well, did you actually connect as user scott?